# How can I check to make sure a new password is a set length with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, passwords

I'm working on a password reset function and trying to check to make sure the new password is at least 7 characters. It will run and pass the new password to the controller and set it as the password for the user but it just uses whatever was entered instead of checking to make sure it meets the password requirements. Thanks for any suggestions :)

Here's the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace [CompanyName].Models
{
    public class ResetPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [ValidatePasswordLength(7, ErrorMessage = "New passwords must be a minimum of 7 characters, please try a different password.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the page to reset the password:

```
@model [CompanyName].Models.ResetPasswordModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ResetPassword";
}

@if (Model == null)
{
    <p>
        We could not find your user account in the database.
    </p>
}
else
{

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.infieldlabel.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("label").inFieldLabels();
        });
    </script>
    <h2>
        Reset Password</h2>
   <p>
   Please enter your new password below.
   </p>
     <p>
        Note: New passwords are required to be a minimum of 7 characters in length.
    </p>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <div style="position: relative;">
       <fieldset>
            <legend>Reset Password</legend>
        <label for="NewPassword" style="position:absolute; top: 24px; left: 16px;">New Password</label>



            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
            </div>
            <br />
        <label for="ConfirmPassword" style="position:absolute; top: 64px; left: 16px;">Confirm New Password</label>     


            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="reset Password" />
            </p>

        </fieldset>

    </div>
    }
}
```

Updated model code:

```
[Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 7, ErrorMessage="New passwords must be a minimum of 7 characters, please try a different password.")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(Guid secureID)
        {
            int id = secureID.FromSecureID();
            var model = new ResetPasswordModel();

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(Guid secureID, ResetPasswordModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int id = secureID.FromSecureID();
                var user = Database.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ID", "Sorry! We could not find your user name in the database, please try again.");
                    return View(model);
                }
                //else (model.NewPassword == null) {
                //return View();
                //}
                user.PasswordHash = model.NewPassword.ToSha1Hash();
                Database.SubmitChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
        }
```

Updated controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(Guid secureID, ResetPasswordModel model)
        {

            if(ModelState.IsValid)
               {  
                int id = secureID.FromSecureID();
                var user = Database.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ID", "Sorry! We could not find your user name in the database, please try again.");
                    return View(model);
                }
                //else (model.NewPassword == null) {
                //return View();
                //}
                user.PasswordHash = model.NewPassword.ToSha1Hash();
                Database.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
            }

            return View(model); 
        }
```

Updated model code:

```
namespace [CompanyName].Models
{
    public class ResetPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New Password")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The new must be at least 7 characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]
        public string Password { set; get; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm New Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you checking the validity of the model in the controller action before performing the password change logic?.. `if(ModelState.IsValid) ...` ?

Comment: I thought the `SqlMembershipProvider` had options for this... do they not meet your requirements?

Comment: @M.Babcock I'm not sure, I'll have to look into that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Properties in your View model will take care of it.

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New Password")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]
    public string NewPassword{ set; get; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password")]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm New Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { set; get; }
```

and in your controller action, you can check for the ModelState.IsValid property to see if the Validation failed or not

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ResetPassword(Guid secureID, ResetPasswordModel model)
 {
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // Validation correct, Lets save the new password and redirect to another action
   }
   return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Okay I tried that, I'll update the code in my question in just a second. It still seems to not be working, and the reference to NewPassword in the controller where it actually writes the new password to the database broke...

Comment: @Blake ModelState.ISValid property is coming as false ? did u use breakpoints and see where it is breaking ?

Comment: I would but I can't debug it with breakpoints until I fix the errors and it's still breaking on the reference to NewPassword in the controller when I try to debug it.

Comment: What is stopping it you from debugging using breakpoints. is it a compile time error ?

Comment: When I put the breakpoints in and try to debug it I get the "there were build errors" message and the only options are to fix the errors or to run the last successful build. Maybe I'm missing something... I'm fairly new at this...

Comment: @Blake: That means there are some compile time errors. So click on "No" and it will list the errors.Double click on each error and it will take you to the error line.Fix that first,I think you property name was "NewPassword" and i gave "Password". try changing that and see. I will change in my answer as well.

Comment: Okay I edited my code and changed that property name and it worked, I should have looked through it a little better! I put the break point in and started debugging and tried to reset the password again, it doesn't hit the break point but it does show an error if the password is under 7 characters which it wasn't doing before. It doesn't change the password though, it just says "Could not find a property named Password."

Comment: @Blake : Glad that your initial problem is fixed. I guess you are using "Password" variable some where in your code and i guess it should be "NewPassword".If you are running in debug mode, you can findout where it is breaking.

Comment: Well it isn't breaking, it's an error in the program showing up saying it can't find a property named password, is there anyway to tell exactly where it was getting the property name from so I know where to change it?

Comment: do a find ( Ctrl+F) in your project, if you cant find it from the list of errors you get while building

Comment: I found it, it was in the model. Once I changed it everything worked great!! Thanks so much for all of your help!! :)

Comment: @Blake : Glad to know it is working for you. It is that easy brother

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `ValidatePasswordLength` is, but `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute` should suffice and is handled by MVC binders and validators (and also on the jQuery.validate side, too).

```
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 7)]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

Then in your controller you can have an action like this:

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        //do something with the valid model and return
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I changed the model like you said but it still isn't doing anything when a password is entered... I edited my question and posted the new code.

Comment: That sounds fine. Did that work, in conjunction with the ModelState.IsValid check?

Comment: No it's still not working, I'll update my question again and post the code from the controller too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PasswordValidator.

```
// Check if the Password has changed
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
{
    // Get the first PasswordValidators... it must do
    var pwd = userManager.PasswordValidators[0];

    // Check whether the Password is valid
    result = await pwd.ValidateAsync(userManager, user, model.Password);
    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
        return View(model);
    }

    // Hash the new Password
    user.PasswordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, model.Password);
    bDirty = true;
}
```

You can eliminate this line from the View.

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 7)]
```